# Is there anyway to upgrade to jelly bean while internal memory and resetting

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3, factory-reset

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with ICS. I want to upgrade my phone to Jelly Bean OS, but I don't have a good enough WiFi connection or enough knowledge, so I want to take the phone to a phone repair center to be upgraded. I have lot of sensitive files on it. I cant remember where some of them were in My phone. Is it possible to upgrade it to Jelly Bean while factory resetting the Phone, because the repair people should not have access to internal files ?. I can do this in my old phone by completely removing everything but I don't know about Android phones.

Comment: It's not clear to me how repair people are related to updating the OS. Why can't you upgrade to Jellybean and then factory-reset later?

Comment: I have not enough knowledge and uninterrupted wifi connection to do so

Comment: So you want to take it into the repair shop and have them update the OS?

Comment: yes, it's easy and it's not cost much

Comment: OK, so why can't you just factory-reset it before taking it into the shop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever give your phone to a repair person or a rep at a carrier store you should assume your data can and will be looked at.  Unfortunately, I saw this all the time while working for Verizon.  We had reps that couldn't wait to get their hands on a phone and start looking through pictures and other private files of customers.  I've actually seen reps save customers pictures to their own device!  It's one of the many, many reasons I quit.  Bottom line: Anything on your phone can potentially be accessed and seen.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. An update by default saves all files and settings. But you should do a factory reset before giving it to the service people(be sure to backup all files before resetting).

To reset, goto

> Settings > Backup & Reset > Factory Reset

After you press OK, your phone will be reset & all old files, apps, settings, etc will be deleted.

Comment: Except those on internal/external SDCard, unless explicitly specified (not all devices offer this). By default, a factory-reset usually does *not* touch SDCards.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't on any of my devices. Titanium Backup uses the 'internal SD' on my devices and is not deleted by factory reset through Settings OR through recovery.